# Type mis-match error in VBA for Excel countdown timer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple timer in Excel using VBA code.  However, I'm receiving a run-time error type mismatch in one of the applications.

Included in the timer are stop and start buttons.  All code below.

The error occurs in this line:

```
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
```

The error is type mismatch variant\string vs variant\integer.

The code is exactly what is shown on an youtube video.  In the video it worked just fine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbJeGG_Xv8M

Here is the code for the buttons and the routines.

Can someone please advise a fix?  I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   starttimer
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   stoptimer
End Sub

Sub starttimer()
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick"
End Sub

Sub nexttick()
   Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
   starttimer
End Sub

Sub stoptimer()
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "nexttick", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Except for indentations and some red fonts, this appears to be the same code.  Am I missing something?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBSFj.gif)

Comment: So you're saying it works for you?

Comment: Check the link (gif)

Comment: at work...it's blocked

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value
```

Is returning a value that's most probably a string. You need to change the Format of the cell to the custom format at the beggining of the video.

Click the cell, press Ctrl + 1 -> Custom Format -> write "m:ss"

Comment: The format of the cell was already hh;mm:ss.  I tried h:mm:ss and m:ss.  Same error.

Comment: That isn't what I'm looking for.  I want the counter to display hhhhh:mm:ss

Comment: Custom formatting doesn't seem to help...the cell shows mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm under pretty much all formats.